# LINUX - Extracting a substring and appending it to a file:

Tags: linux, bash, append, substring, cat

Sorry if this has a real easy answer I'm just not finding,

This is what I currently have but I'm unable to append a specific portion of the file and not all of it:

> cat /Directory/Filetoexamine.txt >> firsta.txt
>
> sleep 60
>
> cat /Directory/Filetoexamine.txt >> firsta.txt

these files' outputs would be along the lines of:

> Date 01/01/1990                   098800 01            GBP
> 0.0000001282 -0.0000001342 0.0000001282 0.0000001282 -0.0000001342 0.0000001282 -0.0000001342 EUR -0.0000001222 0.0000008977 -0.0000001222 0.0000008977 -0.0000001222 0.0000008977 CAD -0.000033342 -0.000055342 -0.000033342 -0.000055342 -0.000033342 -0.000055342

The above is all one line output and the number of spaces between data is changing constantly. I want to extract everything with "G" as a starting point and append it as a new line to firsta.txt. e.g: "GBP 0.0000001282 -0.0000001342 0.0000001282 0.0000001282 -0.0000001342 0.0000001282 -0.0000001342 EUR -0.0000001222 0.0000008977 -0.0000001222 0.0000008977 -0.0000001222 0.0000008977 CAD -0.000033342 -0.000055342 -0.000033342 -0.000055342 -0.000033342 -0.000055342"

So i would have a file(firsta.txt) with a single line per 60 second interval check of the same origin file.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, there's a single line in `/Directory/Filetoexamine.txt` and, from that file, every 60 seconds, you want to extract _"starting from GBP up to the end of line"_ and append it to `firsta.txt` as a new line?

Comment: With GNU and BSD `grep`, you can use the `-o` option: `grep -o 'G.*' /Directory/Filetoexamine.txt >> firsta.txt`

Comment: You could also look into `tail` if you only want the last x lines from the file.